# Why I can't proceed to enter other values to the same variable with std::cin?

Tags: c++, cin

When I enter a value for the group_input variable, the program finishes, and I can't enter a value for the fio_input variable. If I enter a short value, I can proceed to enter a value for the fio_input variable. What's the problem?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned char group_input, fio_input, result[7] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    cout << "\n    Enter your group name: ";
    cin >> group_input;
    cout << "\n    Enter your full name: ";
    cin >> fio_input;
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with using: `std::string` instead of fixed arrays? They are bound to give undefined behavior... C++ is extremely lenient when it comes to checking bounds and what you have here is simply *Undefined behavior*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking for a name, which is an array of `char`s - a [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::string group_input, fio_input;

    std::cout << "\n    Enter your group name: ";
    std::cin >> group_input;
    std::cout << "\n    Enter your full name: ";
    std::cin >> fio_input;
}
```

You shouldn't use `use namespace std;` read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) why.

Also if you want to input names with spaces use `std::getline(std::cin, str);` instead. Because if you `std::cin` `"Roger Jones"` to `fio_input` it will only save `"Roger"`

Comment: Thank you for the solution!

Answer (score 2):

When you read into a `char` variable, the system will read *characters*. And a single `char` can only store a single character, so that's what will be read.

If you give a multi-character input then the first character will be stored in `group_input`, and the second in `fio_input`.

If you want to read strings (which seems to be what you want) then use `std::string`.

Using `std::string` is especially important if you want to avoid buffer overflows. C++ doesn't have bound-checking of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```
cin >> group_input;
```

you read from the standard input and write the result to an `unsigned char` variable. How many bytes will be read? This depends on the overloaded `operator >>` invoked by the above line. In your case, both "input lines" invoke an overload for the `unsigned char`, as this data type can only store one byte, it reads one byte. Hence, you can either input one-character names for both variables, or you change the data type of `group_input` and `fio_input` to something else, e.g. `std::string`. In this case, the `operator >>` overload is invoked that reads anything up to the next whitespace (but not including it) byte, where "whitespace byte" includes tab, newline etc.